# Название пункта ListView

Tags: android-sdk, android

Как узнать имя пункта списка `ListView`, при обработке события `OnItemClickListener`?

Comment: Извините, я не совсем понял. Вы хотите узнать на какой по счету пункт вы нажали или узнать что написано в конкретном пункте?

Comment: Второе нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У OnItemClickListener есть параметр View v.  Оттуда и берите все данные  Eсли вы не используте кастомный вид то скорее всего название можно определить так:

```
TextView tvText = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
String text = tvText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: @Romanzi вы знаете что такое каст/cast/приведение типа?

Comment: @Barmaley это вы наверно мне) сорри, я просто прямо тут писал, поэтому забыл написать. Спасибо за исправление)